# Using the output of a variable substitution in the input to a wildcard expansion

Tags: bash

Looping through a directory with specific extension in bash, e.g.

```
for file in ./*.{png,jpeg,jpg}; do
  ...
done
```

I am trying to set a variable

```
extension="png,jpeg,jpg"
```

Then loop using the varible, eg.

```
for file in ./*.{$extension}; do
  ...
done
```

When I enter it in this way the script searches for files with extension `./*.{png,jpeg,jpg}`.

How do I get it to search for `./*.png` then `./*.jpeg` then `./*.jpg` using a variable?

Answer (score 1):

ignore case sensitive on extensions array

cat 62231525.sh

```
extensions=( png jpeg jpg )
path=/opt/
for ext in "${extensions[@]}"; do
        find "${path}" -type f -iname "*.${ext}"
done
```

Works with:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
..
```

Distro:

```
cat /etc/os-release | grep PRETTY
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

Comment: You don't need `find`; just set the `nocasematch` option and use `for f in *."$ext"` as an inner loop.